# I want to allow only specific people to view videos uploaded to Firebase storage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

Upload your video to Firebase storage.
I want my videos to be viewable only by certain people.
I also tried a signed URL, but after all, anyone can see it if it's within the deadline.
How can I determine if the person who accessed it can view it?

Answer (score 0):

Download URLs from Firebase and signed URLs from Cloud Storage both allow read-only access to anyone who has the URL. There is no way to prevent someone who has such a URL from reading the file.

If you want to control who can access the file, you should sign the user in with Firebase Authentication and access the files through the Firebase SDKs only. With that combination, you can use security rules to control which of them can read the data.

Also see the documentation on [getting started with security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/get-started) and these examples of [common scenarios](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics).

Comment: thank you!
Is it possible to get the URL of the video tag and access it so that it cannot be viewed?

Comment: If by URL you mean download URL, then the answer is: no.  If you want to access the data by a download URL, the data will be readable by anyone who has that URL.

Comment: thank you! Does that mean that Firebase storage can't prevent the URL from being retrieved from the browser's validation mode and accessed directly?

Comment: There is no way to prevent someone who has a download URL from Firebase from reading that file.